# iOS: cellFowRow not called for UITableView contained in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uicollectionview

My app contains a UICollectionView, in which each cell contains a UITableView. The table view's number of rows method is being called correctly, but the cellForRow method is never called. Here is the relevant code:

Setting up the table views (in view did load):

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"OrganizationCollectionCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"OrganizationCollectionCell"];


    tableViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:recipOrgs.count];

    for (NSDictionary *orgDict in recipOrgs) {

        int index = [recipOrgs indexOfObject:orgDict];


        OrganizationTableView *tableView = [[OrganizationTableView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionView.frame];

        tableView.index=index;
        tableView.parentCon=self;
        tableView.dataSource=tableView;
        tableView.delegate=tableView;

        [tableViews addObject:tableView];

    }
```

CollectionView's cellForItem:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"cellForItem CollectionView");
    OrganizationCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"OrganizationCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell==nil) {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrganizationCollectionCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    OrganizationTableView *tv = [tableViews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (tv.orgAlerts==nil) {
        [tv getAlerts];
    }

    cell.tableView=tv;
    cell.tableView.frame=collectionView.frame;
    NSLog(@"%f %f",cell.tableView.frame.size.height,cell.tableView.frame.size.height);

    return cell;

}
```

The "getAlerts" method:

```
-(void)getAlerts{

    orgAlerts = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSString *orgID = [[parentCon.recipOrgs objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"id"];

    [[EDAPIStore sharedStore] getAlertsForOrganizationWithID:orgID WithCompletion:^(NSArray *alerts, NSError *error) {

        if (alerts) {

             orgAlerts = alerts;
            [self reloadData];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        }

    }];
}
```

OrganizationTableView's numberOfRowsMethod:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"number of rows");
    NSLog(@"orgAlerts.count: %d",orgAlerts.count);
    if (orgAlerts.count==0) {

        return 1;
    }else{
        return orgAlerts.count;
    }
```

I have verified that numberOfRows is returning the right number (around 30), but the cellForRow method is never called. The collection cell and table view cell are both defined in their own xib.

Comment: Maybe you should post this to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Maybe.

Comment: Don't mind if I do...http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44974/ios-cellfowrow-not-called-for-uitableview-contained-in-uicollectionview

Comment: CodeReview is for reviewing working code, not for debugging code.

Comment: @YuchenZhong somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu even If it were on topic on [codereview.se] it would not be allowed...

Comment: @YuchenZhong Please read [CR's on-topic page](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and actually verify that a question would be on-topic on the target site before suggesting migration. CR isn't a debugging service, and isn't a dumping ground for anything SO doesn't want to debug either. This question *has a specific programming issue* and is on-topic for Stack Overflow. Upvoted.

Comment: What I notice is that you're setting the tableView frame to the collectionView frame and that seems to be inherently problematic.  Shouldn't it be set to cell.bounds in this case?  Since cellForRow will only be invoked for visible rows, if the frame is hosed and there are no visible rows, cellForRows would never be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your table views' `dataSource` and `delegate` in your view controller's `viewDidLoad`, inside your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, get a reference to the `UITableView` in the `UICollectionViewCell`, and set its `dataSource` and `delegate` there. This seems to be the way of doing it in iOS for any view with a delegate and is put inside either a `UITableViewCell` or a `UICollectionViewCell`. So if you find yourself building forms using `UITableViewController` where you have `UITextField`s inside the `UITableView`, set the text field delegates inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

May I also add that it's probably very expensive on memory to keep a strong reference to all the `UITableView`s in your collection view cells. Your collection view could be reusing a "prototype" collection view cell instead that has been customized to have a `UITableView` inside. Then, in your view controller, keep a two-dimensional `NSArray` as the collection view's data source. The first dimension is for your collection view, and the second the data source of every table view.